# Flutter in_app_purchase queryPastPurchases() returns empty list on iOS

Tags: flutter

Why does queryPastPurchases() return a populated list with my subscription on android, but returns an empty list on iOS?

I have a physical iOS SE phone, my apple user is added as an tester in testflight, I've added a subscription in App Store Connect, and I am able to buy the subscription(in testflight). However queryPastPurchases() returns an empty list...

```
  // Gets past purchases
  Future<void> _getPastPurchases() async {
    QueryPurchaseDetailsResponse response =
        await _iap.queryPastPurchases();

    for (PurchaseDetails purchase in response.pastPurchases) {
      if (Platform.isIOS) {
        InAppPurchaseConnection.instance.completePurchase(purchase);
      }
    }

    setState(() {
      _purchases = response.pastPurchases;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out there was nothing wrong with the code.

In order to make it work I had to create a sandbox user.
Then I had to log out from my current logged in AppID on the phone.
Then I had to "Edit Scheme" in Xcode from Release to Debug.
Then I ran "flutter run" in terminal.
Then I purchased my NonConsumable subscription, and in the dialog I had to enter the sandbox user email and pwd.

**Updated:**
Also I had to create a completely new subscription in app store connect, because the original subscription got trapped in a state were it was not bought nor purchasable. This was due to the fact that the `completePurchase` was done at the wrong place in my code.
It should not be done in `_getPastPurchases()`, but rather in the actual purchase logic.

So put `completePurchase` here:

```
_subscription = _iap.purchaseUpdatedStream.listen((data) => setState(() {
    _purchases.addAll(data);
    for(PurchaseDetails purchase in _purchases){
        if(purchase.productID == 'subName'){
            //SOLUTION
            if (Platform.isIOS) {
                InAppPurchaseConnection.instance.completePurchase(purchase);
            }
        }
    }   
}));
```

PS: I don't remember if I had the completePurchse in the for loop or outside...

Comment: I have the same problem, but these steps didn't seem to help. I can purchase the subscription with sandbox user, and it is successful, but when I queryPastPurchases() after, it returns an empty array. Did you do anything else?

Comment: Sadly it's not working again... I don't know what made queryPastPurchases contain a purchase :/ I guess I'll remove this answer. My solution has been to create a consumable product which is my subscription that I have to store in my database. With this solution I wont get autorenew and apple will take a bigger cut...

Comment: What i noticed is thet Appstore does not return "Non Renowable Subscription" and makes you handle the expiry yourself.

Comment: Also take note that test flight users gets autogenerated sandbox accounts when testing the app.
That means they will handle like sand box account, and not like a "normal account".
If you and your test flight testers experience different results, this might be why.

Comment: Has anyone of you found a solution? I currently face the same issue.

Comment: @Christer Thank you so much, i was stuck on this for ios.

Comment: Can someone explain me the process and what is querypastPurchases for ? I am a bit confused as the plugin is poorly documented. I am handling my purchase in the purchaseUpdatedStream callback, but when a user starts my app, I am supposed to call querypastPurchases right ? Do I need to verify (server side) these purchases again ? (Like during an auto renew for example).

Comment: getAvailablePurchases and getPurchaseHistory are identical on iOS. For consumable purchases, it is recommended to use your server side to keep track of how many are still available.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is currently a known bug of the plugin and as of today there is no other solution than using the unofficial plugin that works better....

You can find the current status of the bug [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/43957) and the unofficial plugin [here](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inapp_purchase)

Comment: In doubt whether I should use a workaround persisting purchases on Firebase.

Comment: I would say normally no, and normally the IAP should be able to reliably handle this for you (in the case of a restore purchase for example) but my paranoiac side somehow tell me to do duplicate a user purchase somewhere in my database just in case... Duplicating these kind of things at 2 different places are usually a bad idea cause you will have issues keeping them in sync. The source of trust should be what the IAP is returning you, when it works correctly.

Comment: specially because of cancellations. I know situations where the iPhone user contacted Apple to cancel a purchase made by a child - and Apple restored. Don't know how long it took, but I can imagine weeks. In my case, since the purchases are vey inexpensive, I chose to duplicate purchases in Firebase and, if the App finds it in iAP or Firebase, I consider it ok. From time to time, I check manually the differences.